# Не получается получить ответ на URL, хотя через браузер заходит без проблем

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет! Такая проблемка, написал код, для попытки отправить запрос на сервер, и узнать нет ли редиректа. Работает со всеми URL однако вчера обнаружил странную вещь, не могу подключиться к этому URL:
'http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1'

Вот код:

```
import httplib2

url = 'nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1'

connection = httplib2.HTTPConnectionWithTimeout(url)
connection.request('HEAD', '/')
response = connection.getresponse()

if response.status in range(301, 304):
    if response.getheader('Location').startswith('https://' + url):
        self._options['href'].replace('http://', 'https://')
```

p.s. Что я упустил ? Может лучше использовать какую-то другую библиотеку ?
Буду благодарен любым ответам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вы похоже используете библиотеку неправильно. У меня вот так работает

```
>>> url = 'nl.wikipedia.org'
>>> connection = httplib2.HTTPConnectionWithTimeout(url)
>>> connection.request('HEAD', '/wiki/ISO_3166-1')
>>> response = connection.getresponse()
>>> response.status
301
```

Вообще можно urllib2 попробовать как альтернативу

Comment: Это то что мне нужно, спасибо большое, помогло!

Answer (score 4):

Прежде всего нужно указать какие конкретно ошибки возникли у вас в коде. Чтобы не нужно было код копировать себе и запускать. Конкретно здесь вылетел `getaddrinfo failed`, что означает, что IP адрес хоста не может быть найден.

Параметры в HTTPConnectionWithTimeout - это **хост** и порт. Хост != URL. Для вашего адреса хост - это `nl.wikipedia.org`. А вся остальная часть (`/wiki/ISO_3166-1`) - это путь (path). Еще в URL должен быть явно указан протокол(scheme) (http, https. mailto, ftp) и порт(?), но в данном случае библиотека проставит их за вас. Еще в URL могут присутствовать параметры (query) и якорь (fragment) - [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) Также проверки на редирект не имеют много смысла, потому что Wiki перенаправляет все http запросы на 443 порт (на https). Соответсвенно, полный пример выглядит так:

```
host = 'nl.wikipedia.org'

connection = httplib2.HTTPConnectionWithTimeout(host)
connection.request('HEAD', "/wiki/ISO_3166-1")
```

Есть прекрасная альтернатива - [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). requests сам разделяет URL на хост, порт, протокол и т.д. Удобно.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!